# How to implement Custom Events?

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, events

How do I correctly implement custom events? I thought the following should work, but I never receive CustomEvent.READY in the main Model

```
package mvc
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public dynamic class CustomEvent extends Event
    {
       public static const MY_EVENT:String = "myEvent";
       public static const READY:String = "ready";

    public function CustomEvent(type:String)
    {
        super(type);
    }
}
}
```

In the Model.as which extends AbstractModel which extends EventDispatcher

```
private function initWorld():void {
        _worldModel = new WorldModel();
        _worldModel.addEventListener(CustomEvent.READY, update);
}
```

Then in WorldModel.as which extends AbstractModel which extends EventDispatcher, I dispatch an event, but update is never called. why?

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(CustomEvent.READY));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_worldModel.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.READY));
```

You must instantiate a CustomEvent, not an Event. Big difference.

You could also use your custom event to pass additional parameters with the dispatched event, which will prove amazingly handy if you make use of your CustomEvent heavily

```
package com.b99.events 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author bosworth99
     */
    public class AppEvents extends Event
    {
        public static const APP_READY       :String = "application ready";
        public static const XML_LOADED      :String = "XML has loaded";
        public static const CHANGE_COMPLETE :String = "state change complete";
        public static const PAGE_ADDED      :String = "page content added";
        public static const PAGE_REMOVED    :String = "page content removed";
        public static const LIBRARY_LOADED  :String = "external library loaded";
        public static const IMAGE_LOADED    :String = "external image loaded";
        public static const LOAD_ERROR      :String = "external load failed";

        public var arg:*;

        public function AppEvents(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false, ...a:*) 
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            arg = a;
        }

        override public function clone():Event 
        {
            return new AppEvents(type, bubbles, cancelable, arg);
        }

    }
}
```

You can then pass any number of arguments along to a receiving function:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new AppEvents(AppEvents.LIBRARY_LOADED, false , false, _name, _library, _names));
```

And access them in the recieving function as an array.

```
private function onLibraryLoad(e:AppEvents):void 
        {
            _digestExternalLib.removeEventListener(AppEvents.LIBRARY_LOADED, onLibraryLoad);

            var currentIndex:int = AppData.navLocations.indexOf(e.arg[0], 0);

            AppData.libraries.push(e.arg[0]);
            AppData.libraryCon.push(e.arg[1]);
            AppData.libraryNames.push(e.arg[2]);

        }
```

I yanked this from a functioning project... but you should be able to gather the important bits... 
Good luck!

Comment: great thanks that looks really useful indeed! Turns out my event was being fired before the listener was initiated. a bit silly really.

Comment: In this case, there's no need to dispatch an instance of CustomEvent class.

Comment: @Omer = you're totally right. Since the OP's customEvent adds no extra functionality, the static const is all thats required (and could be held anywhere). In this case, however, the question was "how to implement custom events" and not "how to use static constants"...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see anything wrong with the code. Just to test, try adding this statement at the end of initWorld() method:

```
_worldModel.dispatchEvent(new Event(CustomEvent.READY));
```

If your update() method is called, that would indicate that your existing dispatchEvent() method isn't being called.

Comment: mmm adding that test works as expected. My dispatchEvent method is being called since I have traces either side, very odd.

Comment: But your're not actually making use of your custom event - only the static constant found in the custom event class.

Comment: silly mistake, I was initiating WorldModel which was firing the event, before the listener was created...