# Custom eventListener Flash AS3

Tags: xml, flash, addeventlistener

Not sure if this is the best option but thought maybe if I could use an eventlistener that would save some time. I am loading an XML file once a second and want there to be triggers if specific values are in the XML so far I have this:

```
//TIMER THAT LOADS XML ONCE A SECOND
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(100,2); // 1 second
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);
myTimer.start();

function runOnce(event:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("HELLO");
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myxml.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

}

function processXML(e:Event):void {
            trace("load XML");
            myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
            trace(myXML);
            }
```

Now I want event listners that do something if "direction" is equal to Left or Right:

```
addEventListener(myXML.LEFT, movieMC_Left);
addEventListener(myXML.LEFT, movieMC_Right);

//movieMC_Left and movieMC_Right functions that do something.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a post a little while ago about [implementing custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979331/how-to-implement-custom-events/5979560#5979560). It may prove useful to you. I kind of get what you are doing here - but you are missing a key point, the dispatching of an event:

```
function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    if (myXML.direction == "Left")
    {
       this.dispatchEvent(new XMLEvent(new XMLEvent.LEFT));
    }
    else
    {
    this.dispatchEvent(new XMLEvent(new XMLEvent.RIGHT));
    }
}
```

This assumes you've created a class that extends Event called XMLEvent (read my post if you have questions about that), and it contains the static const LEFT and RIGHT. It also assumes the class you are dispatching events from inherits from EventDispatcher (which it does if its a sprite or movieclip).

Otherwise = your setup ought to work.

What are you doing, exactly? Driving animation via XML? hmmm. Your logic is potentially flawed in that -  if your load takes longer than a second (based on your time) you will start throwing errors.

Anyway - cheers

Comment: Well I am driving animation based off the data being written into an XML file from a Kinect Camera. Just messing around now but would like to get it working. The camera updates the XML once a second all of the files swf and xml are in the same directory so should load pretty quick. I will take a look at your post and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Neat. Kinect hacks look very cool, sad i haven't had a chance to mess around with one. I would be careful about that load issue, work it into a try...catch or boolean checker or something to ensure the last load was a success. I've just been nailed by stuff like that in the past... :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Event types are just strings. So to listen for two different events you can do this:

```
addEventListener("XML left", onEventRightCalled);
addEventListener("XML Right, onEventLeftCalled);
```

For an extra level of type checking you can make your event types contants.

```
public static const XMLLEFT:String = "XML left";
public static const XMLRIGHT:String = "XML right";
addEventListener(XMLLEFT, onEventRightCalled);
addEventListener(XMLRIGHT, onEventLeftCalled);
```

So in your process XML function, you will loop thru you XML object looking for the direction variable. When you find what you are looking for, dispatch an event:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event(XMLLEFT, true));
```

One last thing: Be sure to make the listener functions, onEventRightCalled, and onEventLeftCalled.