# addEventListener with ruturn in AS3 - How?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, return, addeventlistener

I'm a new Flash AS3 job but I have a big problem using some OOP concepts like return from methods, when I needs a Event Listener code. The problem is that the function from Event Listener cannot return a value. How can I work with this issue? This is a code sample that I using on my AIR app. This code I want to re-use in other situations that I want to parse a directory files.

```
private function initApp():void
{
    try
    {
        // Seta o diretoório de molduras
        var directory = diretorio_mestre.resolvePath("molduras/animacao");
        directory.getDirectoryListingAsync();
        directory.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, listaHandler);

    }
    catch (erro:ReferenceError)
    {
        mostraMensagem("Problemas com a listagem do diretório.", erro.errorID);

    }

    // Percorre arquivos
    function listaHandler(evento):void
    {
        // Contador
        var i:int = 0;

        // Conteúdo
        var contents = evento.files;

        for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) 
        {
            var nome:String = contents[i].name;
            var nome_array:Array = new Array();
            nome_array = nome.split("_");

            // Formata para ordenar
            arquivos_animacao.push ( { nome:contents[i].name, tamanho:contents[i].size, ordem:nome_array[0] } );

        }

        // Ordena para a ordem de númeração
        arquivos_animacao.sortOn("ordem", Array.NUMERIC);

        // Continua o processo
        // How can I return!?!?!

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass extra arguments along with a dispatched event? This is a common issue with flash / air, and it just means you need to create a custom event and extend it with extra parameters.

I made a post not too long ago detailing how to do this right here: ["how to implement custom events"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979331/how-to-implement-custom-events/5979560#5979560).

The main idea is you pass arguments at the end of the method sig when dispatching the event, and picking them up as an array on the receiving end.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's don't. I want a method to sync the DIRECTORY_LISTING event with the result, to use that information later. If I trace the result of the event I receive null, if it does not complete. How can I tell to other method that this is complete without the return?

Answer (score 1):

Ok first off never nest one function inside of the other it is not OOP.

```
private function initApp():void{
  try{
    //Seta o diretoório de molduras
    var directory = diretorio_mestre.resolvePath("molduras/animacao");
    directory.getDirectoryListingAsync();
    directory.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, listaHandler);
  }catch(erro:ReferenceError){
    mostraMensagem("Problemas com a listagem do diretório.", erro.errorID);
  }
}


private function listaHandler(evento):void{
  var contents = evento.files;
  for (var i:int = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    var nome:String = contents[i].name;
    var nome_array:Array = new Array();
    nome_array = nome.split("_");
    arquivos_animacao.push ({nome:contents[i].name, tamanho:contents[i].size, ordem:nome_array[0]});
  }
  arquivos_animacao.sortOn("ordem", Array.NUMERIC);
  this.dispatchEvent( new Event("GOTRESULTS") );
}
```

Now where ever you instantiated the class you just listen for the GOTRESULTS event

```
var myClass:whatEverYouNamedIT = new whatEverYouNamedIT( );
myClass.addEventListener( "GOTRESULTS", gotResults )

function gotResults( e:Event ):void{
  trace(myClass.arquivos_animacao);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Whilst nesting functions can make code harder to read; I disagree with the statement that it's 'not OOP'...

Comment: He should have said, "its not a good OOP practice", which is true because it isn't.